# Pronunciation of “comedian” and “chameleon”

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

I can't figure out the difference in pronouncing "comedian" vs. "chameleon." I looked up their pronunciations in many dictionaries and audio sources, and practiced a lot, but my pronunciation still confuses Merriam-Webster Dictionary app's voice input function, which relies on Google's voice recognition technology. 80% of my attempts at "chameleon" are recognized as "comedian," while 100% of my "comedian" are registered correctly. Even for those "chameleon" cases, the Dictionary app was confused and listed "comedian" as candidate words.

I understand that the app is probably not the best tool to judge my pronunciation, but it is objective and reproducible. For comparison, my wife's pronunciation of "chameleon" are always correctly registered. And her "chameleon" pronunciations have never had "comedian" listed in candidate words, which means that the software thought that there was no confusion at all in her pronunciation. So this somehow proves that her pronunciation is much better than mine, at least according to Google's voice recognition software.

What is the trick for pronouncing "chameleon" correctly, so people (or Google) can understand what I mean when I say "I saw a chameleon the other day"?

Comment: The main difference is between /d/ and /l/, so it sounds like you’re not distinguishing those two sounds clearly enough. Going by your user name, I’m guessing you’re Chinese, in which case you should have a d/l distinction in your own language as well. Does your app also get other minimal pairs mixed up when you say them, like _bidding/billing_, _real/read_, _wailing/wading_, _willow/widow_, etc.?

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I think I have found where I did wrong. Scott's comment below gave me the best hint. It should be (ka meel yun), while I was pronouncing it as (ka mee lyn). The former pronunciation always registers correctly with Google assistant and other voice recognition software.

Comment: Huh, **come again**?

Comment: So maybe the software thinks that *chameleon* ends /-i.ən/ and *comedian* ends /-i.ɪn/. That's probably true for most people without the [weak vowel merger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_high_front_vowels#Weak_vowel_merger) (like me), but a huge number of native speakers have the weak vowel merger, and so wouldn't make this distinction at all. I think native speakers (maybe unlike the software) generally would distinguish these two words by whether the consonant is /l/ or /d/.

Comment: @PeterShor: As far as I know, *-an* would be /ən/ and not /ɪn/ for non-weak-vowel-merged speakers. For example, the 1989 OED entry for "arithmetician" gives the pronunciation as "/əˌrɪθmɪˈtɪʃən/" or "/ˌarɪθmɪˈtɪʃən/".

Comment: @sumelic: I definitely have different weak vowels in *chameleon* and *comedian*.  But neither is the vowel I have in *rabbit*, which is something like /ɪ/. On further consideration, the vowel in *chameleon* is closer to /ɐ/ than to /ə/. If the software is making decisions based on weak vowels, I suspect it's because of some runaway machine learning algorithm that isn't processing language the way English speakers do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course the consonants in the middles of the words is a big difference. 
But another distinction I make is that I pronounce “comedian”
as a distinct 4 syllables (**ka mee dee un** or **ka meed ee un**),
whereas I pronounce “chameleon” as 3½ syllables (**ka meel yun**). 
The American Heritage Dictionary supports me here:

> [comedian](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=comedian):
>
>   kə-mē
>   **′**
>   dē-ən
>
> [chameleon](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=chameleon):
>
>   kə-mēl
>   **′**
>   yən, -mē
>   **′**
>   lē-ən

Answer (score -3):

These two words have very different phonetics.

***Comedian***

C (pronounced like the c in 'car' but just the c, and is a hard c) - 'om' - 'ede' - 'ian' (ian like the the name Ian)

See here: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=34Sb0_HbL54

***Chameleon***

Pronounced like:

'car' - 'me' 'lee' 'on'

See here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEqHM4vXKFk

Comment: Are the first vowels in *chameleon* and *comedian* really different? The [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/chameleon) [Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/comedian) Online doesn't think so. And the only person I've heard pronounce it *Carmeleon* was Boy George, when he was singing *Karma karma karma karma karma karmeleon*.

Comment: These words are definitely pronounced differently! I prefer to offer practical advice here, rather than academic musings.

Comment: I have to disagree;  the first syllable of [*chameleon*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/chameleon) does not sound like the first syllable of [*cartel*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cartel). At least, not in any pronunciation I can find online.

Comment: I’m really surprised to see you write the pronunciations like that, because I was going to say that I pronounce “comedian” as a distinct 4 syllables (**ka mee dee un** or **ka meed ee un**), whereas I pronounce “chameleon” as 3½ syllables (**ka meel yun**). The American Heritage Dictionary supports me here: [“comedian”](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=comedian) vs. [“chameleon”](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=chameleon). And yes, there is no “R” in either word.

Comment: @Scott gave me the best hint. I always pronounced it as (ka mee lyn). After changing my pronunciation to (ka meel yun), the voice recognition systems are much happier with it. If you could write that up as an answer, I'd accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @PeterShor Boy George doesn’t pronounce the first syllable anything like ‘car’ either. He clearly sings a schwa. Apparently a three-syllable realisation of _chameleon_ exists (I can’t say I’ve ever noticed it), but apart from that, the only difference between the two words is the d/l. This answer gives very confusing and unintuitive phonetic respellings that moreover seem to me to be completely wrong.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I've just listened to it again, and you're absolutely right. Either my memory or my hearing was playing tricks on me.